# recursion method with 2d array (java)

Tags: java, recursion

i have to write a method,
The method receives a parameter of two-dimensional array of integers. The method returns the number of the row which has the highest sum of the integers.**I'm allowed to use only recursion! no loops allowed!**-of course i need to make a private method that will sum a row as a single array and then i have to do another private method that compares the rows, but it doesn't really work since the method i wrote is only for a 1d array, and i need to compare a row from a 2d array..

appreciate all kind of help..

some of my code:

```
private  int rowSum(int[] array, int index) {//the sum of an array(1d array)
        if (index == array.length)
            return 0;
        else
            return array[index] + rowSum(array, index + 1);
    }

**public int maxRow(int[][] a){------!!!---the problem...

    }**
```

Comment: Is it so difficult to extend 1d array code to 2d array?

Comment: Tiny pointer - in `maxRow`, `a[1]` is a 1 d array

Comment: maxrow is just like sum row, except it compares sums and returns the min row of adjacent arrays

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem, if it is, be sure to tag it as such in the future.

Comment: @dicarlo2 `homework` tag is deprecated. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: Evgeniy Dorofeev's solution is certainly the one you are looking for, however I would warn that part of learning programming is *doing* the work, not just reading someone else's work and understanding it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Code:

```
public class MainClass {
    static  int contents[][] = { {1, 2 , 3, 4} , { 4, 5, 8, 7}, { 4, 2, 8, 7}, { 4, 5, 0, 7} };
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(getIndexOfRowWithHighestSum(contents, 0, 0));
    }
    public static int getIndexOfRowWithHighestSum(int[][] twoDAray, int currentIndex,int indexWithHighestSum){
        if(currentIndex>=twoDAray.length){
            return indexWithHighestSum;
        }
        int sum1 = getSumOfArray(twoDAray[currentIndex], 0) ;
        int sum2 = getSumOfArray(twoDAray[indexWithHighestSum], 0);

        indexWithHighestSum = (sum1 > sum2)?currentIndex:indexWithHighestSum;

        return getIndexOfRowWithHighestSum(twoDAray, currentIndex+1,indexWithHighestSum);
    }
    public static int getSumOfArray(int[] array, int currentIndex){
        if(currentIndex>=array.length){
            return 0;
        }
        return array[currentIndex]+getSumOfArray(array,currentIndex+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try calling a recursive method from main with arguments:

- array[][]
- current column index
- current row index
- current row sum
- highest row index
- highest row sum

I got it working here, so it is definitely possible.
It's about 15 lines of code.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As a starter exercise, try to change the signature of your `rowSum` function into this:

```
int rowSum(int[] array, int index, int sumSoFar)
```

You should be able to write the function such that the recursive part's return expression is just a recursive call:

```
if (...) // exit case
  return sumSoFar;
else
  return rowSum(...);
```

(This is now a tail-recursive implementation.)

Armed with that mindset, think about how you would write:

```
int indexOfMaxValue(int[] array, int index, int maxValueSoFar, int maxIndexSoFar)
```

Once you get those, you should be able to combine those two concepts together.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is ready to run and test:

```
public class RecursionSum {
    /* Sum a row until <code>index</code>. */
    private static int rowSum(int[] a, int index) {
        if (index == 0) { return a[0]; }
        // add the current element to the recursive sum
        return a[index] + rowSum(a, index - 1);
    }

    /* Sum a whole row. */
    private static int rowSum(int[] a) {
        return (a.length == 0) ? 0 : rowSum(a, a.length - 1);
    }

    /* Find the index of the array having the max sum until <code>index</code>. */
    private static int maxRow(int[][] a, int index){
        if (index == 0) { return 0; }
        // compare the current row's sum with the recursive max row's sum,
        // update index when it's a new winner
        int maxIndex = maxRow(a, index - 1);
        return (rowSum(a[maxIndex]) < rowSum(a[index])) ? index : maxIndex;
    }

    /* Find the index of the array having the max sum. */
    public static int maxRow(int[][] a){
        return a.length == 0 ? 0 : maxRow(a, a.length - 1);
    }

    /* very simple test */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a1[][] = {};
        int a2[][] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
        int a3[][] = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 90}, {5, 6, 7}, {300, 4, 9}, {4, 6, 12}};
        System.out.println(maxRow(a1));
        System.out.println(maxRow(a2));
        System.out.println(maxRow(a3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] mat = { { 2, 6, 5, 4 }, { 3, 17, 2, 6 }, { 1, 3, 21, 0 } };

    System.out.println(maxRow(mat)); // 1

    int[][] mat1 = { { 2, 6, 5, 4 }, { 1, 3, 21, 0 }, { 3, 17, 2, 6 } };

    System.out.println(maxRow(mat1)); // 2
}

public static int maxRow(int[][] mat)
{
    return maxRow(mat, 0, 0, -1);
}

private static int maxRow(int[][] mat, int row, int maxSumInRow, int maxRowNo)
{
    if (row == mat.length)
        return maxRowNo;
            
    int sumRow = sumRow(mat, row, 0);
    
    if (sumRow > maxSumInRow)
    {
        maxSumInRow = sumRow;
        maxRowNo = row;
    }

    return maxRow(mat, row + 1, maxSumInRow, maxRowNo);
}

private static int sumRow(int[][] mat, int row, int col)
{
    if (col == mat[row].length)
        return 0;
    
    return mat[row][col] + sumRow(mat, row, col + 1);
}
```