# Finding which matrix row has the highest sum java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive non-static method that for each given matrix will return the row number that has the highest total sum. I am not allowed to use static method and for loops (in any methods I write).

I think the solution is using three methods:

1. (private) count the total sum of a given row.
2. (private) compare total sum of row `i` with total sum of `i+1` using method #1
3. (public) check that the matrix has more than one row and apply #2 on row `0`.

I feel like I overcomplicate things here with my way of solving this problem. If anyone willing to suggest me better algorithm I'll be glad to try.

Anyway, I believe I'm ok with #1 and #3. My problem is with #2. I don't know how to set a row number variable:

```
public class Matrix {

private int[][] _mat;

public Matrix(int sizeRow, int sizeCol) {
   _mat = new int[sizeRow][sizeCol];
}

private int maxRow(int row) { //Recursive method #2: comparing sum of i and i+1
        int rowNumber;
        if (row <= _mat.length) {
            if (rowSum(row, 0) > rowSum(row+1,0)) {
                rowNumber = row;
                return maxRow(row+1);
            }
            else {
                return rowNumber;
            }
        }
        else {
            return rowNumber;
        }
    }
..
public int maxRow() {..} //Recursive method #3

private int rowSum(int i, int j) {..} //Recursive method #1

}
```

My problem is with the var `rowNumber`. It has not been initialised and if I will initialise it it will be set to `0` each time I recall the method.

I have found exactly the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252486/) but the method suggested is static and receives array.

Comment: So just pass `rowNumber` as an argument to `maxRow`.

Comment: What is _mat? What data type is it?

Comment: @Jason edited question. `_mat` is a double array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to return the index of the row with maximum sum, you can do the following:

```
private int maxRow(int current_index, int max_index) {
    if (current_index == _mat.length) {
        return max_index;
    } else if (sumRow(current_index) > sumRow(max_index)) {
        return maxRow(current_index+1, current_index);
    } else {
        return maxRow(current_index+1, max_index);
    }
}

maxRow(1, 0); //method call
```

The first argument `current_index` stores the index that you are currently testing, while argument `max_index` stores the visited index with maximum sum until now.

The first clause ensures that you return whatever index had the maximum sum value once you reach the end of the array.

The second clause updates `max_index` once you find a row with sum higher than what you had before.

The third clause just iterates to the next row when the above doesn't happen.

You can call the method with `current_index=1` and `max_index=0` so you don't need to initialize `max_index` with an invalid value.

If you want to improve performance, you can also add a new argument `max_value` to store the current max sum, so you don't need to call it at every recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how you can retrieve the index of the row with the highest sum.

```java
public class MaxRowFromArray {

    private final int[][] values;

    public MaxRowFromArray(int[][] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    private int sumOfRow(int[] row, int rowIndex, int sum) {
        if (rowIndex > row.length - 1) {
            return sum;
        }
        return sumOfRow(row, rowIndex + 1, sum + row[rowIndex]);
    }

    private int highestRow(int column, int highestIndex, int highestRow) {
        if (column > values.length - 1) {
            return highestIndex;
        }
        int sumOfRow = sumOfRow(values[column], 0, 0);

        if (sumOfRow > highestRow) {
            return highestRow(column + 1, column, sumOfRow);
        }
        return highestRow(column + 1, highestIndex, highestRow);
    }

    public int highestRow() {
        int highest = highestRow(0, 0, -1);

        if (highest == -1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No row can be found with the highest sum.");
        }
        return highest;
    }
}
```

Test

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MaxRowFromArray max = new MaxRowFromArray(new int[][] {
                { 1 },
                { 1, 2 },
                { 1, 2, 3 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4}
        });

        int expectedHighest = 3;

        int highestIndex = max.highestRow();

        if (highestIndex != expectedHighest) {
            throw new AssertionError(String.format("Highest index %s was not the expected highest %s.",
                    highestIndex, expectedHighest));
        }
        System.out.println("Highest: " + highestIndex);
    }
```